# Merge Custom (Manual Entry) Column onto New Table with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a new table in PowerBI Desktop where the initial table is created using DAX, ie. New Table = Distinct(Roster[Name]) to source the most up to date list of users, and then would like to create a new column on the table which I can manually update and enter in dates that people would be available. For example, a table that looks like [Name] [Next Available] where name is sourced with DAX and the Next Available column is an editable field.

Is this possible?

Appreciate any help you can provide.

1. I've tried to create a new table using "Enter Data" which prompts you to create a new table (but I'm looking to merge with the current roster table).
2. I've tried creating a new table using "Enter Data" and then merging this table with the Roster Table but the "Enter Data" table does not update with the most recent roster changes.
3. I've tried creating custom columns to Roster table but can't figure out a way to create an editable column on an existing sourced table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in Power BI (that I know of) but Power BI is not designed to be a database or a spreadsheet. Data entry generally needs to happen before loading it to Power BI.